# ListBox iteration WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-phone-7

I have a Listbox bound to an observable collection and XAML snippet shows what each item will contain (textblocks and Slidercontrol ) Slidercontrol is set to invisible intially

```
         ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="500">

                 <stackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0"  Width="100"........
                   <TextBlock Margin="200,10,0,0" Width="100"........ 
                 </StackPanel>

                <Slider Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="100".................

                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <TextBlock Width="100" TextWrapping="Wrap"..............
                   <TextBlock Width="100" TextWrapping="Wrap"...............
                 </StackPanel>                                
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I want to first check observableCollection list object for certain Time property , if the time is inside the current system time , i want to Activate corresponding slider control  ListBox Item and update it the silder indicates progress in time and updated until end time  and user cannot move it  , but  How to i access or iterate ListBoxitem so that i can then activate the Slider control via visualhelptree.HELP!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Again**

---

First off all, as long as your are just using the `Slider` to shoe just the progress in time, then the right control to use is the `ProgressBar` control (The `Slider` control is used to let user change a value, for example changing the volum of a media player). Moreover, you can implement this more easily, without the use of the `TreeVisualHelper`. Lets say that your are binding to the following `ObservableCollection` object:

```
ObservableCOllection<MyObject> Collection;
```

Edit `MyObject` class and add `double` property to indicate the progress value for the `ProgressBar`, more over add a `Timer` object to fire every 5 minutes to check the two times and decides whether to enable the Slider or not by changing the boolean value, sothing like the follwoing:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public double ProgressValue { get; set; }
    private System.Timers.Timer TimeChecker;

    public MyObject()
    {
         // 5 Minutes = 5 * 60 Seconds = 5 * 60 * 1000 Milliseconds
         TimeChecker = new Timer(300000);
         TimeChecker.Elapsed += CheckTimes;
    }


    public CheckTimes()
    {
         // Check StartTime and EndTime to decide whether to enable the slider or not.
         if(...)
         {
              // Here you can add the appropriate value to indicate the current progress
              ProgressValue == ....;
         }
         else
              ProgressValue == ....;
    }
}
```

Then, in the item template, bind your `ProgressBar.Value` property to the `ProgressValue` property, it will be something similar to the following:

```
<BrogressBar Value="{Binding ProgressValue}"/>
```

This way each item will have its own timer. A better alternative to have just one timer that iterate through the collection each 5 minutes and do what is necessary.

Comment: i have 2 properties inside MYObject StartTime and EndTime, i would like to enable the Slider after start time and update it every 5 min untill end time is reached and then disable the Slider control appreciate your help.

Comment: Mohammed Good stuff got other ideas with binding for other controls, but how would i update the value of the slider, basically the slider represents the progress of time, may be i should have said this earlier.

Comment: @AshwinNagarajan, are you using the slider just to show the progress in time? Or the user can drag and change it's value?

Comment: @AshwinNagarajan, the change the Slider control to a ProgressBar. Check out my new updates, and feed me back

Comment: can i do this IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled_Progress}" Visibility="Collapsed"  Value="{Binding ProgressValue}"....

Comment: You don't need to disable/enable the ProgressBar, any ways the user won't be able to interact with it, it is just intended to show the progress. On the other hand, if you want to show/hide the ProgressBar then you need to create a Visibility property in MyObject class and bind the ProgressBar.Vibility to it something like `<ProgressBar Visibility={Binding IsProgressVisible}.../>`

Comment: The binding for progress bar works great thanks a lot, but i am unable to hide the Progress bar when not active, tried IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled_Progress}" in addition to what u had mentioned , it just dosent hide. thanks a TON for the help man.

Comment: Welcomes brother, what is the type of the `IsEnabled_Progress` property? it has to be of type `Visibility` and not of type `bool`

Comment: OHH Mighty One i ask thee question again ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650512/wpf-listbox-collapsible

Answer (score 1):

Try a ValueConverter - you need something like this:

```
<Slider Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="100" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Time, Converter={StaticResource IsTimeNearSystemTimeConverter}}" />
```

**EDIT**

sounds like youll need to do multibinding with a multivalueconverter

```
public class BetweenTimesMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var time1 = (DateTime)values[0];
        var time2 = (DateTime)values[1];
        var current = DateTime.Now;
        return time1 > current && time2 < current;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

add the above class as a static resource in you xaml, then use it like this:

```
<Slider Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="100">
    <Slider.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource betweenTimeConverter}">
            <Binding Path="EarlyTime" />
            <Binding Path="LateTime" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Slider.IsEnabled>
</Slider>
```

Comment: but i guess thats more like static,I have two time Properties in my observableColletion list object  if the time is between these two times i ebanle the converter and update it every 5 min and disable when the time is no more between start and end times , i would appreciate if you can tell me how can  i write a dynamic IvalueConverter class for this scenario , appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks Dean appreciate your reply,basically the slider represents progress of time, i need to find a way to update the slider value, thanks for the help