# WPF LISTBOX collapsible

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

THere are few items in My Listbox , items are completed, Active and pending ( depends on my internal logic) , i want to hide completed  and Pending items , on press of listbox/button the pending or Completed items should collapse displaying the items ( like row wise collapse), would appreciate your help guys.

Comment: 3 Diff listboxes(Completed,active,pending), button for completed/pending and when pressed make it Visible/collapsed, but it does not have that row scroll down effect (like folding/unfolding).

Comment: WPF or WindowsPhone? see also  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints